# Remove Html Element when the construction of element is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

I have img html element which i want to hide or remove at certain condition, but the construction of element is unknown and whenever i try to console it. it gives null. Element is constructed using ext Js3.4.

Jquery :

```
$('#FACILITY_ID_field__div').find('img.x-form-trigger').remove();
```

HTML :

```
<div id="FACILITY_ID_field__div">
   <input type="hidden" id="id32" name="FACILITY_ID" value="5776" placeholder="Facility ID, name, or location" class="fieldsXtraLength">
   <div class="lov-sleek" id="ext-gen109">
      <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" id="ext-gen110" style="width: 450px;"><input type="text" id="idlov32" name="FACILITY_ID_lov" class="x-superboxselect-input x-form-text x-form-field x-form-focus" value="" placeholder="Facility ID, name, or location" style="width: 425px;"><img src="/ext/resources/images/default/s.gif" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger " id="ext-gen111"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please try after few milliseconds `window.setTimeout( function(){ $('#FACILITY_ID_field__div').find('img.x-form-trigger').remove(); },10);`

Comment: i cannot put any setTimeout and all. any other alternative

Comment: Wrap your statement with `$(document).ready(function () { /* here */ });`

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the element with jquery if you created it with extjs ? Remove it with extjs. This is important, because the html element corresponds to extjs javascript objects. If you remove with jquery, the extjs objects will be out of sync with the html dom.

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to see element is visible or not then you have to perform  this---**

```
if $('#FACILITY_ID_field__div').find("img[class='x-form-trigger']").is(":visible"){
   $('#FACILITY_ID_field__div').find("img[class='x-form-trigger']").remove();      
}
```

**It think it will help you**